# CXF plugin version for Grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails, plugins, cxf, grails-plugin

Does anyone know what is the latest version of cxf-client plugin I should install for grails 1.3.7? The last I used was cxf 1.5.4 but I need a newer one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to Apache cxf site, you can find all the available version and check out which is the newer

https://cxf.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however I am looking for cxf client version that is compatible with grails 1.3.7, some of those won't work with 1.3.7.